# hasClass() returning false despite selecting based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm selecting elements based on their class, for example:

```
$.each($('#gender_chart .nv-slice'), function(i, value) { });
$('#gender_chart .nv-slice').each(function() { });
```

No matter which I use, if I then print out hasClass() for $(this/value), I get false. For example:

```
console.log($(this).hasClass('nv-slice'))
console.log($(value).hasClass('nv-slice'))
```

As you can see, I'm looping through all elements with the class 'nv-slice', but then calling `hasClass('nv-slice')` on any of these elements returns false.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: all elements with `nv-slice` class are `<g>` tags

Edit 2: the reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to call `$(this).trigger('hover')` and I can't, as for some reason it won't access the correct element

Comment: Is that a typo, You are missing the last single quote at `console.log($(this).hasClass('nv-slice')) ` ?

Comment: Yeah typo sorry - fixed

Comment: Works for me (http://jsfiddle.net/52uwLmLb/1/). There must be something else going on which you aren't aware of. Break the structure down and be absolutely sure you have the right elements etc. lots of logging!

Comment: Show your HTML code. This is not a Javascript code bug, Javascript is fine.

Comment: I know I have the right elements, cause using the inspector I can see the class is 'nv-slice'. Also if it helps, the elements with class 'nv-slice' are all <g>

Comment: May be $(this) contains some other selector. Try using console.log($(this).attr('class'));

Comment: console.log($(this).attr('class')); gives me nv-slice, so not sure why this isn't working

Comment: jsfiddle.net/rubbpdqv it works like this. Maybe there is something wrong in your mark up

Comment: I'm not writing any of the HTML, it's generated dynamically as I'm using a graph from the nvd3 library

Answer (score 3):

Until v1.12/v2.2, jQuery didn't support `addClass`, `hasClass`, etc. on SVG elements. In v1.12 and v2.2, they added support for XML elements (including SVG).

If using an older version, you can use `classList`:

```
console.log(this.classList.contains("nv-slice"));
```

...or of course, fall back to the old-fashioned attribute check:

```
console.log(/\bnv-slice\b/.test(this.getAttribute("class")));
```

...which you may have to do because IE's [support for `classList`](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList) is very recent (and [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq) says that even IE10 doesn't have it on SVG nodes, just HTML nodes).

```js
$('#gender_chart .nv-slice').each(function() {
  snippet.log("hasClass says " + $(this).hasClass("nv-slice"));
  snippet.log("classList.contains says " + this.classList.contains("nv-slice"));
  snippet.log("class attr check says " + /\bnv-slice\b/.test(this.getAttribute("class")));
});
```

```html
<div id="gender_chart">
  <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 95 50"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="nv-slice" stroke="green" fill="white" stroke-width="5">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="10" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.12 and 2.2, this function works with SVG elements.  Source: https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: @BrianNguyen: Excellent!